# How can I invalidate all user logins on Exchange across all browsers, devices and machines?

Tags: windows-server-2016, exchange-2016, exchange-server

I believe multiple of the user accounts on this exchange server to be compromised. I have already reset the user passwords of the affected accounts, but I want to be certain that any session that was authenticated using the old credentials is invalidated.

Exchange 2016 CU9 v15.1
Windows Server 2016 v1607

Comment: Considered restarting the various networking protocols used to access the mail server?

Comment: I have, but i am unsure if that's going to invalidate any kind of "remember me" tokens

Comment: As far as I know, if you reset the password for users, the user will receive prompt credential and the users should enter the correct credentials. The previously cached credentials will expire and are no longer available

Answer (score 0):

If you disable and re-enable the user again in Active Directory, any current sessions should be invalidated.